# Generate node-xmpp script for browser

Tags: node.js, browserify, node-xmpp

I am developing an application on php. I need a chat on xmpp nodejs. Sending a message will go from web page.

I found [enter link description here](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp). In terminal everything works fine. But how do I attach client script to the browser?

I generate script by:`browserify node_modules/node-xmpp/lib/node-xmpp-browserify.js > nodeXmpp.js` and attach it to web page:

Then trying to use it:

```
$(document).ready(funcrion(){
var client = new XMPP.Client({
    jid: 'user@example.com',
    password: 'password'
});
```

});

And chrome console telling me:

> Cannot load StringPrep-0.2.3 bindings (using fallback). You may need to `npm install node-stringprep` nodeXmpp.js:3669

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:3254

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'resolveSrv'

Object # - its "dns".

And before  generate script i install node-stringprep.

Question is how build xmpp client script for browser.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your code, but the following should work fine:

```
require('node-xmpp/lib/node-xmpp-browserify.js');
var client = new XMPP.Client(opts);
```

Comment: i try this, but its not work. can you show step by step instructions?